# Android TextView text splitting system

Tags: android, textview

I'm going to make an app for which I need to know how does android split the text in it's TextView.Because of the splitting the text doesn't go out of the window it retains in side a bound.

The help what I need is like the image

[image]

In the image the text didn't overlap with the triangle. So I need a sample code spinnet which will help me to do that. Or idea to how to do it will also help me.

Comment: Their is a github library for custom shape . Look at it it may help  https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way, I think - split one TextView on several ones (for example - 3, or more if you need precise approximation).

[image]